# Alternating background colour on UITableView rows

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using the following to set alternating background colours for my cells:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (![cell isKindOfClass:[AlbumDetailsCell class]]) {
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:229/255.0 green:229/255.0 blue:229/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.backgroundColor = color;
    }
    else {
        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:214/255.0 green:214/255.0 blue:214/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
}
```

This messes up when I scroll fast in the table view. How do I prevent it from messing up the colours?

Comment: @jrturton Due to the fast scrolling, the Doppler effect applies, and the background colors are shifted towards red or blue, depending on the direction of the scrolling.

Comment: @jrturton The colours get repeated on some cells. I want them to go "grey, white, grey, white…" but they are "grey, grey, white, grey, white, white…".

Comment: @H2CO3 Woah no! I mean the actual colour of the cell!

Comment: @H2CO3 that's the downside of scrolling so smooth it approaches light speed.

Comment: @H2CO3 That only applies if your eyes are not perpendicular to the screen.  If you are perpendicular to the screen this just turns into a case of length contraction, therefore we should increase the size of the cell height to resolve that issue first.

Comment: @H2CO3 Um, Can U guyz halp me wif mah tableviewz?

Comment: @duci9y did u find any solution? i am facing same problem.

Comment: @AnumAmin Yes I did. I will post it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using custom drawing code in my cells which used the background colour property as the fill colour. Hilarity ensued. I now use a custom property on my cells to set the background colour and also call `setNeedsDisplay` on it.